# FTP file download problem. Getting readonly file exception

Tags: android, ftp, download

```
public class FtpDownloadDemo {
public static void Connection(String filename) {
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try {
        client.connect("ftp.domain.com");
        client.login("admin", "secret");

        //
        // The remote filename to be downloaded.
        //
       ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.IMAGE_FILE_TYPE);

        fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);

        //
        // Download file from FTP server
        //
        client.retrieveFile("/" + filename, fos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fos != null) {
                fos.close();
            }
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}

I am using this code to download some image file. but at  ***fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);*** getting file.jpeg is readonly file exception. i am using commons.net jar file for ftp connection. please help me where i am wrong.

Comment: How is this associated with Android? Where is filename defined? It probably points to a location where you have no write access rights.

Comment: actually this is a demo. in my android application i made a function for this. and passing the filename as parameter.

Comment: You need to pass it a valid filename of a place where you can write, such as the external storage directory after declaring appropriate permission in the manifest.  Try just writing some dummy data to the file output stream without the FTP, you will probably get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supplied the host, username and password when creating the class and then called this to download the file. Those guys were right it probably was trying to write to the root or something. I have been using commons-net-2.2.jar for this client.

```
public void GetFileFTP(String srcFileSpec, String destpath, String destname) {
    File pathSpec = new File(destpath);
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    BufferedOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        client.connect(mhost);
        client.login(muser, mpass);

        client.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
        client.setFileType(org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        fos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                              new FileOutputStream(pathSpec.toString()+"/"+destname));
        client.retrieveFile(srcFileSpec, fos);
        }//try 
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("FTP", "Error Getting File");
            e.printStackTrace();
            }//catch
        finally {
            try {
                if (fos != null) fos.close();
                client.disconnect();
                }//try
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("FTP", "Disconnect Error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }//catch
                }//finally
    Log.v("FTP", "Done");    
    }//getfileFTP
```

Hope this helps.

phavens